# Wordpress Background image Dynamic from post image cover

Tags: wordpress, css

Have been finding an answer around here, but don't found anything related.

So, I'm going to create a wordpress custom theme, here is the condition:
- I want to have **featured post** with **post-image** as **Background-image**

The question is, everytime I'm going to make a featured post, I will need different post-cover-image, how can I make this post image appear as Background image on CSS instead of put it as normal

Because I will need the featured post having a big background (css) + background-size: cover;

Answer (score 0):

add this to your theme - this is to get you started

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); $url = $thumb['0']; ?>
<section style="background:url(<?php echo $url; ?>) no-repeat center center fixed;  -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover; background-position:50% 50%;  *filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.<?php echo $url; ?>', sizingMethod='scale'); *-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='<?php echo $url; ?>', sizingMethod='scale')";">

</section>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```